# YouTube API on iOS Safari, programmatically mute/unmute with custom controls?

Tags: javascript, ios, youtube, youtube-api

My goal is to have videos play, muted, as they scroll into view, using the YouTube iFrame API. This part I have working fine.

What DOESN'T work, on mobile, is trying to give users a button to mute/unmute the video. So, video starts playing and we then want to give the user the option to turn on the sound. Unfortunately, the youtube controls on mobile don't show an option for that. Also, calling `mute()` or `unMute()` on the video, on mobile, has 0 effect. My mute/unmute button works on the desktop, though, so I know it isn't a syntax issue.

I've found various answers on here, but they're all older, and have read the webkit specs regarding rules of video. I `mute()` the video before calling `play()` in order to get them to programmatically start playing on scroll on iOS. Once it's playing, though, is there any magic combination of events that will tell iOS to let the user's organic click interaction impact the player?

The rules say that audio must be controlled by the user, so if the user clicks something to mute/unmute the video, how do I convey to webkit that it's OK?

Comment: I think this is a limitation of Safari and not on Youtube API as stated in [reported issue](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/4373) for muted button disappear in iphone(iOS). You can check [embed YouTube Videos in iOS Applications with the YouTube Helper Library](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper), it is an open source library that helps you embed a YouTube iframe player into an iOS application. Hope this helps you find a workaround regarding your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I managed to get it to work, and I think it was related to the `isMuted()` method of the YouTube API not always returning the correct value. So, I just decided to add/remove a class on the video to manage the mute/unmute state of the video and now it's behaving as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was relying on the YouTube API `isMuted()` method, which returns a boolean, to decide when to mute/unmute a video. After logging the value of `isMuted()`, though, I discovered that for some reason on mobile it wasn't always correct. So, the video would be muted but it would still return false, so it wouldn't fire my unmute function.

The solution was to not trust their API and just toggle an `is-muted` class on my video wrappers when the user taps the button to mute/unmute it. It now works as intended on desktop and iOS Safari.